# Positioning of list/accordion above a button?(Semantic UI)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-8mfdn
<< a rough code sandbox

The accordion overflows the left bar behind the button.

I tried inserting `style={{position: 'absolute', bottom:'2%', overflow: 'scroll'}}` in Accordion or List, but that moves the whole list up.

Is there a way to make the bottom of the accordion above the top of the button, i.e. make the displayed list shorter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-9eqv0?file=/index.js)?

I just gave it a height (obviously you can increase it to fit your needs) and when the content overflows a vertical scrollbar appears.

Comment: Not a bad idea! Though if the browser is narrow enough, it will still appear behind the button. But works for now lol